# Find $x$ on $e^{\cos x}+2\cos x =0$

Tags: calculus

A friend of mine asked me help to find the $x$ on $e^{\cos x}+2\cos x=0$.
However I can't remember how to deal with that $e^{\cos x}$.
Can someone demonstrate how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I know that those are the correct answers, but how do you demonstrate it?

Comment: The $\cos x$ part isn't really the problem. The real issue is that the equation $e^u+2u=0$ has no elementary solution. (The aforementioned Lambert W function works but is not elementary.) That leaves numerical methods.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\cos x$. Then we're solving $e^u = -2u$, or equivalently, $\frac 12 = (-u)e^{-u}$ which implies $u = -W(\frac 12)$.

This value is within the range of $\cos x$ which can be verified with the intermediate value theorem on $f(x) = xe^x$.

Thus the solutions are $$x = \pi -\arccos\left(W\left(\frac 12\right)\right) + 2\pi n \lor x =\pi + \arccos\left(W\left(\frac 12\right)\right) + 2\pi n$$